# How to hide/disabled option to copy link of youtube video?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm embedding a youtube video in the HTML with the following code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7MqMyoxMaW4?controls=0&modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm trying to hide/disable the context menu inside the video. to avoid copy video link.

I was going through API documentation, still couldn't find result.

How can achieve this?

fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/us9rev0b/

Comment: This is one type of patch but we can hide it by following pure JavaScript

_For hide watch later and share button respectively_



**watch later**
`document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-watch-later-button ytp-button ytp-show-watch-later-title")[0].style.display = 'none' `
**share button**
`document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-button ytp-share-button ytp-share-button-visible ytp-show-share-title")[0].style.display = 'none' `

Comment: @HardikMasalawala consider post your comment as an answer.

Comment: please check my answer and accept it if it is matches your desired requirement

Answer (score 0):

This is one type of patch but we can hide it by following pure JavaScript 

**For hide watch later**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-watch-later-button ytp-button ytp-show-watch-later-title")[0].style.display = 'none'
```

and **For share button**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-button ytp-share-button ytp-share-button-visible ytp-show-share-title")[0].style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: this is inside an iframe, you cannot control the iframe element from parent window

Comment: @duchuy This is interesting... The answerer tells it as if they were able to hide it. Though I agree with you, I am curious to know.